# Page break not working in UIWebView

Tags: css, ios, uiwebview

I am trying to create an app for iPad, like iBook. I have loaded a ePub file in it and all is working fine.

I have written a CSS for the webview page. The following is my code to get page break

```
<span style="page-break-after: always" />
```

I have loaded a image, and some text below it. After the image I want the page break, and I want the image to be moved to the next page, but the page break code is not working. I'm not sure that my line of code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about add a style definition like this?

```
<style type="text/css">
  img.pagebreak {page-break-before: always;}
  ...
</style>
...
<body>
...
<img style="pagebreak" ...>
...
```

Comment: NSString *pagebreak = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule(<style type='text/css'>img.pagebreak {page-break-before: always;}</style><img style='pagebreak'>"];
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:pagebreak];